# Creating a table of square roots of a given list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am a newbie to Prolog and trying to develop a simple code to get the following output.

```
?-sqrt_table(7, 4, Result).
Result = [[4, 2.0],[7, 2.64575],[6, 2.44949],[5, 2.23607]] ;
false.
```

However the output I'm getting is,

```
?- sqrt_table(4,7,X).
X = [[5, 2.23606797749979], [[6, 2.449489742783178], [[7, 2.6457513110645907], []]]].
```

I think the issue is in the nested list created by get_sqrt/2. If I can get it flattened down to tuples I think it might work. Your ideas and help are much appreciated.

```
%main predicate
sqrt_table(N,M,Result):-
        full_list(N,M,Out),
        get_sqrt(Out,[Rest,Result]).

%Creates a range of outputs  within the given upper and lower limits
range(Low,Low,High).
range(Out,Low,High):-
        NewLow is Low+1,NewLow=<High,
        range(Out,NewLow,High).

%Creates a list of the outputs created by range/3
full_list(Low,High,Out):-
        findall(X,range(X,Low,High),Out).


%Calculates the square root of each item in the list and gives a list consisted
%of sublists such that [Input,Squareroot of the input]
get_sqrt([],[]).
get_sqrt([H|T],[[H,Sqrt],SqrtRest]):-
        SqrtOf_H is sqrt(H),
        get_sqrt(T,SqrtRest),
        Sqrt = SqrtOf_H.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the head of the second clause of`get_sqrt/2`, simply write `[[H,Sqrt]|SqrtRest]`, i.e., use `(|)/2` instead of `(,)/2`.

In fact, it would be even better to use the more readable and more idiomatic `[H-Sqrt|HSqrts]`, i.e., use `(-)/2` do denote **pairs**.

And in second fact, a better way altogether is to simply state the relation for **one element at a time**, using for example:

```
integer_isqrt(I, I-Sq) :- Sq is sqrt(I).
```

and then to use the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) `maplist/3` to relate **lists** of such elements to one another:

```
?- maplist(integer_isqrt, [0,1,2,3,4], Ls).
Ls = [0-0.0, 1-1.0, 2-1.4142135623730951, 3-1.7320508075688772, 4-2.0].
```

P.S.: Using `flatten/2` always indicates a problem with your data structures, you should **avoid** `flatten/2` entirely. If you need to remove one level of nesting, use `append/2`. But in this case, neither is needed.

Comment: It does work. Thanks. However when the arguments are parsed from the get_sqrt/2 to sqrt_table/2, the first element of the list is lost.

Comment: That's because you have ignored the warning that your Prolog system gives you. What do you think `Rest` is in the following goal: `get_sqrt(Out,[Rest,Result])`? It's where the first element of the list went. Change this goal to `maplist(integer_isqrt, Out, Result)`.